# Azure : Ansible role for deploying ML model integrated over databricks

Tags: deployment, databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow, mlmodel

I have developed ML predictive model on historical data in Azure Databricks using python notebook.
Which means i have done data extraction, preparation, feature engineering and model training everything done in Databricks using python notebook.
I have almost completed development part of it, now we want to deploy ML model into production using ansible roles.

Comment: deploy where? to AzureML, or to AKS as docker?

Comment: Need to deploy over AzureML

Answer (score 0):

To deploy to AzureML you need to build the image from the MLflow model - it's done by using the [mlflow.azureml.build_image function](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.azureml.html#mlflow.azureml.build_image) of MLflow.  After that you can deploy it to Azure Container Instances (ACI) or Azure Kubernetes Service by using `client.create_deployment` function of MLflow (see [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-mlflow-models)).  There is also [mlflow.azureml.deploy function](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.azureml.html#mlflow.azureml.deploy) that is doing everything in one step.

This [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/10/13/using-mlops-with-mlflow-and-azure.html) & [example notebook](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/mlflow/mlflow-quick-start-deployment-azure.html) that show the code for full process of training/testing/deployment of the model using MLflow & AzureML.